I am trying to make a plugin in ROS but the same error always happear:
So I have made a ROS plugin to make a new library and I am trying to test the library's methods by executing one of them by a node in a different workspace. when I execute the node this happen:
[ERROR] [1719244165.939620169]: The plugin failed to load. Error: According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class ik_solver_plugin::iKinematicPlugin with base class type ik_solver_plugin::iKinematicPlugin does not exist. Declared types are
I have tried many options to check the CMakeLists.txt file or the package.xml file or the package_description.xml file but everything seems made correctly to me.
What causes this error and how could i fix it?

What app is the plugin for? Which release of ros? Can you give us a url to a github.com repo containing this catkin package?

I wanted to make an IK solver but I was encountering this error, so in order to compare my work with something else I used the kdl_kinematics_plugin and still encounter the same ERROR. I have only modified the CMake file.
I do not know if the issue lays in the CMakeLists.txt file or else. My idea is to have the IK solver developed in one workspace completed with shared library and have a ROS  node in another workspace. Here the link for the github with the plugin and the node. catkin_ws_10 is the Ik solver and catkin_ws_11 has the node.
https://github.com/Tommaso2025/Plugin

Package Visibility
If you are going to build in separate catkin_workspace in your user account, and then use them at the same time, you need to make the package(s) available by executing cmd source devel/setup.bash in the correct order.
So the steps for your scenario look like:

source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash
build the catkin_ws_10 workspace
source devel/setup.bash  # for catkin_ws_10
build the catkin_ws_11 workspace
source devel/setup.bash  # for catkin_ws_11
execute the app in catkin_ws_11

That said, my opinion is that this approach is more complicated than necessary, because you can simply put the code for both ik_load and kdl_kinematics_plugin side-by-side in the same catkin_ws/src/ directory during development.
Other Fixes

You have the wrong filename in kdl_kinematic_plugin/CMakeLists.txt:

# Install the plugin description file to a custom directory
 install(FILES
-  plugin_description.xml
+  kdl_kinematics_plugin_description.xml
 )


In ik_load/CMakeFiles.txt, your catkin_package() statement should contain no statements:

catkin_package(
-  INCLUDE_DIRS include
-  LIBRARIES ik_load
-  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp pluginlib geometry_msgs moveit_core moveit_kinematics kdl_kinematic_plugin
)


Your xml file has errors. You have:

<library path="lib/libmoveit_kdl_kinematics_plugin">
  <class name="kdl_kinematics_plugin/KDLKinematicsPlugin"
         type="kdl_kinematics_plugin::KDLKinematicsPlugin"
         base_class_type="kinematics::KinematicsBase">

The "path" property should not have the "lib/" prefix, and the value should be the name of the .so file in catkin_ws/devel/lib/, so "libkdl_kinematics_plugin" for your package.
The "name" property should be removed completely (it's now an optional attribute.)

In your load_ik.cpp, you are specifying the wrong class name to the ClassLoader. The second argument is the name of the base class, not the derived class.

  pluginlib::ClassLoader<kinematics::KinematicsBase> load_ik("kdl_kinematics_plugin", "kdl_kinematics_plugin::KDLKinematicsPlugin");

Have you enabled Debug logging for your load_ik ros node? I see some useful messages being logged by pluginlib.
Even with these 4 fixes, your node still doesn't work, but it looks to me like the plugin portion is being successfully loaded and executed.

Hello @Mike973 I have tried to apply the changes in the kdl_kinematic_plugin/CMakeLists.txt and ik_load/CMakeFiles.txt. Even update the githib: https://github.com/Tommaso2025/Plugin/tree/master
I also tried to combine all toghether in the same workspace as you suggsted for package visibility problem but the error is always there.
I was wandering if you can give me some feedback about the kdl_kinematics_plugin_description.xml and plugin_description.xml. In this http://wiki.ros.org/pluginlib/Troubleshooting the point 1.4 says that this kind of error is caused by the plugin.xml file.

I updated my answer to add fixes 3 and 4.

Hello @Mike973 I have updated the code with the fixes you mentioned, as you said the node still does not work. I have enabled the Debug logging but the most useful of it is this:
[DEBUG] [1720046659.811653763]: Attempting to create managed instance for class kdl_kinematics_plugin::KDLKinematicsPlugin.
[DEBUG] [1720046659.811679096]: Class kdl_kinematics_plugin::KDLKinematicsPlugin has no mapping in classes_available_.
I do not understand entirely these messages. To me they are saying that the issue is within the plugin_description.xml or package.xml but to me they are both correct.
